# Create System Tray on ToolStrip in C#

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar, system-tray

I have my own C# `ToolStrip` application (TaskBar) and I would like to put differents items on its System Tray by `NotifyIcon`.

But the problem is I can not successfully create a System Tray into this `ToolStrip`.
I can see my `NotifyIcon` going directly into `System Tray` of Windows TaskBar but I want to see them on my `ToolStrip`.

I don't find (even with Googling) any object like a `System Tray` in C#...

So, my questions are : how we can create a `System Tray` and attach it to new `ToolStrip` ? And if I missed a point ?

Thanks in advance for all answers and if I missed precision or if you want specific code (I think it wasn't necessary in my case), please ask me.

Comment: Do you mean creating a system tray by your own (basically speaking, a rectangle with icons on it) and putting it on top of the Windows's one?

Comment: I've created my own taskbar and I'm using it after killing all explorer processes, so I don't have the Windows' taskbar. 
So yes and no. I want to create my own system tray but putting it on top my own taskbar. Sorry if i misunderstand something.

Comment: You got it perfectly. Actually, I did something on these lines myself some time ago; but I didn't kill the original one from Windows, just put mine on top of it (you can kill all the process and the computer runs without any problem?). The only thing I can come up for this kind of situations is creating the element you want (rectangle with icons) and locate it in the part of the screen you want (simple form positioning); what I guess that you have done with your own taskbar. What do you expect to do other than that? (PS: has been SO down or it was just for me?)

Comment: In future, this program will be located in Registry key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell) so Explorer.exe will not be launched. That's why for my example I kill Explorer.

Yes I think created a rectangle is a good way to succeed. Thanks, I try it on.

ps : it wasn't just for you, StackOverflow wasn't accessible during 10 minutes approximately

Comment: I am happy of having been of any help. (first time I see SO down!)

Comment: I have one question, about the result with the rectangle for my using. Why I want to do this is, I want to put some items into a new Systray because when my `ToolStripOverflowButton` is present, I only can put it to the extrem left or extrem right of `ToolStrip`. And I want my `ToolStripOverflowButton` to be between my `ToolStrip` items.
So I thought to create a Systray like I've said to have the display I needed : `ToolStripDropDown` - `ToolStripButton`s - `ToolStrip.OverflowButton` - and `ToolStripButton`s. I don't know if I'm comprehensible and if your solution is always available ?

Comment: I think that you got the "rectangle idea" wrongly. What I meant was: dimension your form (remove bothers and top buttons, logically) to target the exact geometry you want (that is, a rectangle). All the objects you are referring cannot be put "in the air", but in a form. Summary: on Form_Load, do width of the form = with of the screen and height = the height of the taskbar; locate the form where you want (= at the bottom of the screen) and put in it all the buttons you want to emulate the taskbar (not easy at all); after that account for the left hand side bit (= system tray).

Comment: Bear in mind what you are asking: you don't want to use the default taskbar/system tray (something relatively easy), but you want them to not appear, although keeping the graphical appearance (rectangles on the bottom); thus you have to create everything. On top of that, the associated functionalities (dealing with all the programs and being able to maximise/minimise them, etc.) cannot easily be accomplished (at all).

Comment: My final taskbar is functional, my problem is just for it appearance, to be more user friendly. If you want to see : 
http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/87294_taskbar.jpg
I want to put the ToolStripOverflowButton between IE and shutdown.

Thanks a lot again !

Comment: And how have you put your taskbar in the right location? You have two options: relying on Windows and intending to over-write its version or avoiding it completely and implementing yours (= drawing a rectangle and putting it on the bottom). Either way I guess that you have control on what "this rectangle" contains, thus draw a new small rectangle (the system tray) and locate it where it belongs (right hand side). I seriously don't see the problem, neither what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: I've created a class derived from ToolStrip and when I've finished to initialize it, I'm using this native method.
PInvoke : `[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern UIntPtr SHAppBarMessage(UInt32 dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);`.
MSDN : SHAppBarMessage function -- Sends an appbar message to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : SplitContainer.

With this, I can have a taskbar and a systray in my application.